# Python - Querying dictionaries within dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, nested, querying

I have a question if anyone would be so kind to help me? :) Could you help me with a little bit of code regarding dictionaries within dictionaries:

A simple program that prompts a user for an email address (that must be stored in the database) in order to gain access to the webpage

Here we shall build dictionaries to hold the data... within a dictionary that will hold the entire database:

```
database_of_users = {
                "Cleaus": {"email" : "c@gmail.com"},
                "Jay" : {"email" : "j@hotmail.com"},
                "Tremaine" : {"email" : "t@gmail.com"},
                "Kyla" : {"email" : "k@outlook.com"}
              }
```

Next bit:

```
user_email = input("To gain access to this feed, you must be a member
 of the site. \n\nIf you are already a member, please enter your
 email address below: \n\n").strip().lower()
```

Then:

```
while True:
 if "@gmail.com" in user_email or "@hotmail.com" in user_email or 
 "@outlook.com" in user_email:
   break

elif "@gmail.com" not in user_email or "@hotmail.com" not in 
  user_email or "@outlook.com" not in user_email:
     user_email = input("\nPlease enter a valid email
     address (gmail/hotmail/outlook): \n\n").strip().lower()
```

Here I am stuck on how to search all of the secondary (nested) dictionary value entries within the main dictionary. I have tried turning it into a list first and then calling what I thought would be the value entries in the second dictionary to query them, but it is not working:

```
database_aslist = list(database_of_users.values()
```

I realise the if statement below is just calling the first bit before the 'item' = (key:value), so in this case the name "Cleaus", "Jay","Tremaine","Kyla", but I am just unsure of how to query all data within the main dictionary completely, keys and values included, at the same time? Is it possible?

```
if user_email in database_of_users:
   print("\nOk, I have found you. Please enjoy the show!")
   print("\n\n[GAINED ENTRY]")

if user_email not in database_of_users:
   print("\nSorry, that email address does not seem to be in our database. 
To gain access, please register for one of our packages here:
 \n\n[LINK WHERE THEY CAN SIGN UP]\n\nThank you!\n")
```

Thanking you all in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I've never known a way without walking through the dictionary.  Something like this:

```
    user_found=False
    for user in database_of_users:
        if database_of_users[user]["email"]==user_email:
             user_found=True
             break
    if user_found:
         print("\nOk, I have found you. Please enjoy the show!")
         print("\n\n[GAINED ENTRY]")
    else:
          print("\nSorry, that email address does not seem to be in our database. 
          To gain access, please register for one of our packages here:
          \n\n[LINK WHERE THEY CAN SIGN UP]\n\nThank you!\n")
```

Though, if email is what is being entered, changing the database_of_users to use emails in the first nesting might be the easier way to go if that's an option:

```
    database_of_users={
         "c@gmail.com": {"name":"Cleaus"},
         "j@hotmail.com": {"name":"Jay"},
         ...
         }
```